# How to set classpath in Spring mvc app?

Tags: spring-mvc, jboss7.x

I have two different web apps on my server. One is Spring mvc app and other is struts app. Libraries for these apps are at different locations. Following is my Spring mvc app structure:

[image]

All jar files for Spring mvc app are in `WEB-INF/lib` directory. Following is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>My project</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>route</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>route</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When I run spring app, it shows exception:

```
[org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (MSC service thread 1-6) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.myproject.scm.dao.LoginDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/route-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
```

But when I run Spring mvc app without struts app, it runs fine. Maybe there are conflicting libraries?

Can I add classpath in my Spring mvc app, so that it look library jars at proper location?

Answer (score 0):

JBoss 7 ships with Hibernate 3.  You'll have to exclude it in your jboss-deployment-structure if you want to use Hibernate 4.  Take a look at https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Implicit+module+dependencies+for+deployments for more information on implicit dependencies.